# Extracting data from dataset using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this dataset:

```
LP3I22- M5
01174c-qbFD.raw
L2P2 + p LPI Full ms [150.00-1500.00]
Scan #: 1
RT: 6.11
m/z Intensity   Relative    Resolution  Charge  Baseline

  150.0119         67.3     0.00    152545.44       0.00       26.27
  150.0153         59.3     0.00    269991.72       0.00       26.28
  150.0156         66.1     0.00    288504.16       0.00       26.28
  150.0161         67.2     0.00    172425.14       0.00       26.28
  150.0330         78.9     0.00    167957.34       0.00       26.32
  150.0485         75.0     0.00    208783.14       0.00       26.35
  150.0603        166.2     0.00    220081.53       0.00       26.37
  150.0624         75.8     0.00    189976.39       0.00       26.38
  150.0866         70.1     0.00    233127.77       0.00       26.42
  150.0991         54.8     0.00    193755.25       0.00       26.45
  150.1136         62.9     0.00    184047.91       0.00       26.48
  150.1348         85.4     0.00    206299.06       0.00       26.52
  150.1410         68.7     0.00    225439.47       0.00       26.53
  150.1428         73.1     0.00    205324.42       0.00       26.54
  150.1498         61.2     0.00    199792.59       0.00       26.55
  150.1572         56.8     0.00    160342.95       0.00       26.57
  150.1583         71.4     0.00    187849.53       0.00       26.57
  150.1746         84.7     0.00    211934.81       0.00       26.60
  150.1777         81.2     0.00    251123.45       0.00       26.61
  150.2106         65.7     0.00    198830.13       0.00       26.67
  150.2144         53.7     0.00    190111.53       0.00       26.68
  150.2781         74.0     0.00    187803.52       0.00       26.81
  150.2807         90.7     0.00    174743.38       0.00       26.82
```

How can I extract the data results using regex? I'm not interested in the the first 7 lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming it's in a String called `data`

```
number_re = /\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*/
data.scan(/^#{number_re.source * 6}$/)
```

That will result in the following array

```
[["150.0119", "67.3", "0.00", "152545.44", "0.00", "26.27"],
 ["150.0153", "59.3", "0.00", "269991.72", "0.00", "26.28"],
 ["150.0156", "66.1", "0.00", "288504.16", "0.00", "26.28"],
 ["150.0161", "67.2", "0.00", "172425.14", "0.00", "26.28"],
 ["150.0330", "78.9", "0.00", "167957.34", "0.00", "26.32"],
 ["150.0485", "75.0", "0.00", "208783.14", "0.00", "26.35"],
 ["150.0603", "166.2", "0.00", "220081.53", "0.00", "26.37"],
 ["150.0624", "75.8", "0.00", "189976.39", "0.00", "26.38"],
 ["150.0866", "70.1", "0.00", "233127.77", "0.00", "26.42"],
 ["150.0991", "54.8", "0.00", "193755.25", "0.00", "26.45"],
 ["150.1136", "62.9", "0.00", "184047.91", "0.00", "26.48"],
 ["150.1348", "85.4", "0.00", "206299.06", "0.00", "26.52"],
 ["150.1410", "68.7", "0.00", "225439.47", "0.00", "26.53"],
 ["150.1428", "73.1", "0.00", "205324.42", "0.00", "26.54"],
 ["150.1498", "61.2", "0.00", "199792.59", "0.00", "26.55"],
 ["150.1572", "56.8", "0.00", "160342.95", "0.00", "26.57"],
 ["150.1583", "71.4", "0.00", "187849.53", "0.00", "26.57"],
 ["150.1746", "84.7", "0.00", "211934.81", "0.00", "26.60"],
 ["150.1777", "81.2", "0.00", "251123.45", "0.00", "26.61"],
 ["150.2106", "65.7", "0.00", "198830.13", "0.00", "26.67"],
 ["150.2144", "53.7", "0.00", "190111.53", "0.00", "26.68"],
 ["150.2781", "74.0", "0.00", "187803.52", "0.00", "26.81"],
 ["150.2807", "90.7", "0.00", "174743.38", "0.00", "26.82"]]
```

Comment: Ooooooo very nice! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
lines = IO.readlines('inputfile.txt')
data = lines[7..-1].collect{|x| x.scan(/([^\d]+[\d.]+)/).flatten.map{|y| y.strip}}
```

For a simpler solution that doesn't involve a regex, replace the last line with:

```
data = lines[7..-1].collect{|x| x.split}
```

This all assumes that the data set matches the one you listed and does not contain any unexpected or improperly-formatted values.

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern:

```
^\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*$
```

in multiline mode

Answer (score 1):

```
7.times{DATA.readline}  # discard first 7 lines
res = DATA.map{ |line| line.lstrip.squeeze.split(' ').map{|el| el.to_f } }

__END__
LP3I22- M5
01174c-qbFD.raw
L2P2 + p LPI Full ms [150.00-1500.00]
Scan #: 1
RT: 6.11
m/z Intensity   Relative    Resolution  Charge  Baseline

  150.0119         67.3     0.00    152545.44       0.00       26.27
  150.0153         59.3     0.00    269991.72       0.00       26.28
  150.0156         66.1     0.00    288504.16       0.00       26.28
  150.0161         67.2     0.00    172425.14       0.00       26.28
  150.0330         78.9     0.00    167957.34       0.00       26.32
  150.0485         75.0     0.00    208783.14       0.00       26.35
  150.0603        166.2     0.00    220081.53       0.00       26.37
```

---

The values in res are now floats:

```
 [[150.019, 67.3, 0.0, 152545.4, 0.0, 26.27], [150.0153, 59.3, 0.0, 2691.72, 0.0, 26.28],
 [150.0156, 6.1, 0.0, 28504.16, 0.0, 26.28], [150.0161, 67.2, 0.0, 172425.14, 0.0, 26.28],
 [150.03, 78.9, 0.0, 167957.34, 0.0, 26.32], [150.0485, 75.0, 0.0, 208783.14, 0.0, 26.35],
 [150.0603, 16.2, 0.0, 2081.53, 0.0, 26.37]
```